# Формы html-php

Tags: php, html

у меня есть файл reg.php там регистрация обработчик тот же самый файл reg на и после успешной регистрации выводиться Вы успешно зарегистрировались! но когда обновляешь страницу форма обратно передаеться , header("Location: reg.php"); пробовал работает но, Вы успешно зарегистрировались! исчезает, как сделать чтобы Вы успешно зарегистрировались! оставалось а форма обратно не передовалась при обновлений! ??? помогите плизз!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте сессии. 
если пользователь успешно зарегистрирован выводим сообщение, и вешаем на него сессию. При повторном обновлении проверяем есть ли у него сессия, если есть то выводим желаемый текст, если нет шлем форму. Все просто.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

грубо но:

```
if($_POST['form'])
{
// вы успешно зарегистрировались
} else 
{
/*форма
<form>
поля...
<input type="submit" name="**form**" value=""> // дабы отследить передачу в if
</form>
*.
}
```

думаю смысл понятен

Comment: а другого способа нет? (( просто тут у меня каша, а так проверка строит! если такой логин существует! то выводиться ошибка, у меня когда обновляеться выводиться это ошибка мне это не нужно, нужно чтобы вы успешно зарег сохранилась!

Comment: ну, если $_POST[form] существует, туда впихивай "проверку", если все ГУД, то "успешно зарег", иначе, отображаем форму.
или я вас не понимаю...

Comment: у меня все так жее! но от Post не избавляеться по любому!

Comment: короче, код в студию, еще раз что надо

Comment: я предполагаю, что он хочет чтобы после отправки формы и успешной регистрации, пользователя не куда не перекидывало, а при обновление странички форма заново не отправлялось.